# Creating nested list based on class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently grabbing all elements that have a class of 'section' using jQuery. What I want to be able to do is create a nested ordered list of these sections, with sub unordered list that match the section hierarchy.

For instance, below is the HTML formatting:

```
<div class="section">
    <h1>Here's the section heading</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

    <div class="section">
        <h2>Here's the subsection heading</h2>
        <p>Duis a ornare elit. Sed non fermentum erat. Curabitur porttitor tempor condimentum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the for loop I'm currently using to create a list:

```
var list = $('<ol />');
$('.section').each(function (index, element) {
    var header = $(element).find(':first(:header)').text();
    var item = '<li>' + header + </li>';
    $(item).appendTo(list);
});
```

However, this is returning a flat, one-level list.

```
<ol>
    <li>Here's the section heading</li>
    <li>Here's the subsection heading</li>
</ol>
```

What I want is a formatted list based on the hierarchy of the divs - IE the second section div is nested within the first section div so the second li should be nested in the first.

```
<ol>
    <li>
        Here's the section heading
        <ul>
            <li>Here's the subsection heading</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I've tried a few things but nothing is formatting the list like I want. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Cx676/

```
function buildList(sections, list) {
    sections.each(function (index, element) {
        var header = $(element).children(':header').text();
        var item = '<li>' + header + '</li>';
        $(item).appendTo(list);
        var subsections = $(element).children('.section');
        if (subsections.length > 0) {
            var sublist = $('<ul/>');
            sublist.appendTo(list);
            buildList(subsections, sublist);
        }
    });
}

var list = $('<ol/>');
buildList($('body').children('.section'), list);
console.log(list)
```

You need parse only direct children, not find.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example I have just created similar your solution:

```
var html = "<ul><li>Here's the subsection heading</li></ul>";
function subSection(html){
    $('ol').each(function(){
        $(this).children('li:first-child').append(html);
    });
}
subSection(html);
```

Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/cAwXL/3/)

Answer (score 0):

A minor update to the fiddle created by 'xfx'.
http://jsfiddle.net/subhamsaha1004/Cx676/2/

The code looks very similar:

```
function buildList(sections, list) {
    sections.each(function (index, element) {
        var header = $(element).children(':header').text();
        var item = $('<li />');
        item.append(header);

        var subsections = $(element).children('.section');
        if (subsections.length > 0) {
            var sublist = $('<ul/>');
            buildList(subsections, sublist);
            sublist.appendTo($(item));
        }

        item.appendTo(list);
    });
}

var list = $('<ol/>');
buildList($('body').children('.section'), list);
$('#result').append(list);
```